# Jquery toggle bug on window resize with media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with the toggle button when window resizes. The issue is that I clicked on the toggle which shows up a list of items and i left it open, however when I resize the window the toggle is still left open despite the fact that I put `display:none;`on the media query.

HTML CODE:

```
   <section id="nextprevsection">
   <h2 id="nextprev">View more projects?</h2>
   <ol class="select">
   <a href="heritagetrails.html"><li>Previous Project</li></a>
   <a href="artmovement.html"><li>Next Project</li></a>
   <a href="work.html"><li>Back to work</li></a>
   </ol>
   </section>
```

CSS:

```
.nextprev{
display:none;
}

#nextprev{
display:none;
font-size:16px;
width:200px;
background:url(../img/work/downarrow.png) right no-repeat #333;
color:#FFF;
cursor:pointer;
padding:10px;
margin:auto;
margin-top:-150px;
}

ol.select {
display: none;
background:#666;
width:220px;
margin:auto;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;

}

.select{
display:none;   
}
.select a{
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

ol.select > li:hover {
background: #aaa;
}
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
            //next previous
    var nav = $('#nextprev');
    var selection = $('.select');
    var select = selection.find('li');
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
nav.removeClass('active');
selection.css("opacity","none");
    }
else{
     nav.addClass('active');
}

    nav.click(function(event) {
    if (nav.hasClass('active')) {
    nav.removeClass('active');

    selection.stop().slideToggle(200);  

    } else {
    nav.addClass('active');
    selection.stop().slideToggle(200);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    });


    select.click(function(event) {
    // updated code to select the current language

    $(".select").css("display","none");
    select.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    </script>
```

MEDIA QUERIES CODE:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
/*Next and previous*/

#nextandprev{
display:none;   
}


  .select{ 
  display:block;
  }

  #nextprev{
  display:block;
  }

  #nextprevsection{
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:100px;  
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a screen re-size isn't necessarily going to invoke your code that detects the screen size. One option you have is setting a short timer that periodically checks the screen size and invokes your code.

But that's the lame answer. Try $(window).resize(function(){});

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Basically it wraps the window.onresize event (which I honestly didn't know existed til recently, stupid DOM!!) and let's you do your own thing with it :)

Comment: Rock on dude, happy to hear!